# How to show Git actions in VSCode Source Control window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have Git branch and status (pending commits to be pulled/pushed) listed in the *top* of the the *Source Control* window of VS Code:

[image: vscode source control window]

I want to enable this on another PC, but can't figure out which extension or setting enabled this?

Note: The same informations is listed in the *bottom blue status bar*, but I find the top position more useful.

The VS Code documentation only describes the [git status bar actions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-status-bar-actions).
Ironically, the screenshot they post [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_scm-providers) has the feature set, while the next on posted [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-support) doesn't have it.

Comment: Please check what GIT extentions you installed...

Comment: `mhutchie.git-graph`, `gitlab.gitlab-workflow`, `donjayamanne.githistory`. But they are now installed on both PCs, and the new does not show the status on top.

Comment: This question seems to be entirely about this particular GUI and its extensions, and not about Git at all. Is that right?

Comment: @torek you can say that is correct. I would not say it's not about git at all :-)

Comment: @Morgy, nope, I click in the blue bottom bar.